# dart/flutter : How to convert List of String into Map in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I got list of String from (Shared Preferences)  and the result was  :

```
['{id:5}' , '{id:6}']
```

and I want to check the value for each (id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have List and you want a Map<String,String?>, here is a way of doing it:

```
final list = <String>['{id:5}', '{id:6}'];

final newList = list.map((e) {
  final match = RegExp(r'{id:(\d+)').firstMatch(e);
  return MapEntry('id', match?.group(1));
}).toList();
```

or if you just want a list of the id:

```
final newList = list.map((e) {
  final match = RegExp(r'{id:(\d+)').firstMatch(e);
  return match?.group(1);
}).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is the wrong way to store values in  list, if you have just list of id , you have to make it like : `List<String> l= ["1","2","3","4"];`

then you can convert list to map as follow :

```
List<String> l= ["1","2","3","4"];
  Map<String,dynamic> mapp = {};

l.forEach((element) { 
  mapp["id"] = element;
});
```